# how i can solve : can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float' (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

i'm just newbie for python , can anyone help me this code, im stuck for a week for this problem

here my code:

```
price = {
    "Espresso": 5.80,
    "Americano": 6.90,
}

currency = "$"

print ("welcome coffee machine!\t")
name = input ("can i get your name?\n")

print ("what do you like to order mr/ms " + name + "\n"  )


menu = ("Espresso, Americano")

print (menu)
menu = (input())


quantity = input("How many " + menu + " would you like?\n")
quantity = str(input())

#im stuck at here! T_T 
if menu == "Espresso" :
    price = 5.80
    total = quantity * price
    quantity.append(quantity)
    price.append(price)
    print(total)

elif menu == "Americano":
    price = 6.90
    total = quantity * price
    quantity.append(quantity)
    price.append(price)
    print(total)

else:
     menu()

#invoice receipt

print("Thank you for order " + name + ", please wait your " + menu + " at counter\n")
```

hopefully someone/somebody can help me to solve this problem T_T

Comment: `quantity` should be `int` data type rather than `str`. Also, you cannot `append` a number or a string to a number or a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thank you for you help, i found my answer
here the correct code:

```py
menu = "Espresso, Americano"

print (menu)
order = input()

#changed the quantity variable to an integer so that it can be used in mathematical operations!
quantity = int(input("How many " + order + " would you like?\n"))

#added a total variable and called the calculate_total function to calculate the total 
# price based on the quantity and price of the order.
def calculate_total(quantity, price):
    total = quantity * price
    return total
    
total = calculate_total(quantity, price[order])
```

Comment: For better readability, put the code blocks in backticks that also indicate the language. E.g: 
```python
print("Holla")
```

Comment: alright, tq bro

Answer (score 1):

You are getting error because of this line:

```
quantity = str(input())
price = 5.80
total = quantity * price
```

You are multiplying `string` with `float`.

```
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```